# How to use replace for a conversation text?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to replace name of speakers in chat sentences. Assume I've the following chat.

James: What are you doing?
Lisa: Nothing.
Marcus Ma: me too.

I want to use preg_replace it to be like this.

***James:** What are you doing?

**Lisa:** Nothing.

**Marcus Ma:** me too.*

I've tried but here's what i've get

***James:** What are you doing?

**Lisa:** Nothing.

Marcus **Ma:** me too.*

Please check my code and tell me whats wrong, Many thanks

```
preg_replace("/(\w+:)/i","<b>$1</b> &nbsp; ", $text);
```

Comment: You should try to minimize your example. I understand what you're asking without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part `(\w+:)` to this one `([\w\s]+:)`.

It will include spaces `\s`.

Also set that you want to match only at the beginning with `^`.

The result will be:

```
preg_replace("/^([\w\s]+:)/i","<b>$1</b> &nbsp; ", $text);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this one:

```
preg_replace("/^([^\:]+\:)/i","<b>$1</b> &nbsp; ", $text);
```

It will help if the name consists of any non-word character.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, Hope this will help

```
preg_replace('/^(.+:)\s([\w\s?]+)/i','<b>$1</b> <em>$2</em>',$str);
```